# Application crash and server corrupted file?

Tags: java, crash, infinite-loop

I created an basic TCP socket application with multithreading and where each client would be added to an hashmap where i would send specific messages to specific clients. Today i accidentally applied an infinite while(true) loop to my whole server code. It caused my pc to work very hard and my pc didn't respond anymore. Eventually i was forced to manually shut down my pc and upon opening my server file all code in my java file was removed and replaced with white space. Luckily there was nothing of too much significance in my server file but it made me wonder what caused to remove all code inside my java file?

Comment: A corrupted filesystem might happen, but to specifially have your open java file corrupted is not coincidental. I don't think the restart "emptied" your file.

Comment: In my infinite loop it was infinitely starting threads and adding items to my hashmap. So i would understand the part why my pc started to work very hard but why all the code in my server file was removed is a mystery. This is the first time it has happend to me.